# default method in interface runs with command prompt but not in eclipse

Tags: java, interface, java-8, default-method

```
interface G {
    default void print() {
        System.out.println("G");
    }
}
class M {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("M");
    }
}
class GImpl extends M implements G {}
public class Wierd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        G g=new GImpl();
        g.print();
    }
}
```

i was trying to use default method in interface ,but when compile with eclipse i get error on line 2 -says delete default, but i compile and run with command prompt it runs fine,what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I suppose that only *Luna* supports [Java-8], which version you are using???

Comment: then try the link that TAsk gave you in answer, I wish it will work for Juno.

Comment: Juno is out of the question. The earliest release you can use is Kepler SR2, but will need to additionally apply the Java 8 patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your eclipse still not using `Java8` version please check it might be less than 8.
- Use `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));` to check.
- You may also need to change build path of your project and compiler level in eclipse.

*AND More Important:*

[Installing Java™ 8 support .](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/)

Comment: i got this 1.8.0_05-b13,its 8 only i think

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have installed Java 8 JDK but your eclipse still does not support Java 8. [Eclipse Luna](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) has support for Java 8. To change the compiler options Right Click your project>Properties>Java Compiler>Check on "Enable project specific settings">Then select Compiler Compliance level.[image]